# How to analyze a dump file from a Delphi DLL file?

Tags: delphi, debugging, memory-dump

I'm an escalation engineer on a product which use both [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) and Delphi 2006 code.

In most cases C# issues are debugged with [WinDbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) and Delphi 2006 issues with [EurekaLog](http://www.eurekalog.com/).

But when the issue is a Delphi memory usage, EurekaLog doesn't give enough information to fix the issue, and the only thing I have for debug it is a full memory dump file.

I cannot (or I don't know how to) load the symbol file in WinDbg, because it is a `.map` file and not a `.pdb` file.

So my questions are:

- How do I load the symbols from a .map file in WinDbg? (Converting `.map` to `.pdb` or other.)
- Is there a tool to analyze the dump file for a Delphi application?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**To convert from Map to Dbg symbols:**
- Get Map2Dbg.exe from http://code.google.com/p/map2dbg/
- Put Map2dbg in the same folder as YourApp.exe and its map file
- Execute: map2dbg.exe YourApp.exe

You should get a YourApp.dbg file to use with Microsoft tools….

Comment: Newer version of WinDbg work better (or only?) with PDB files, on the same map2dbg project is tds2pdb located: http://code.google.com/p/map2dbg/downloads/detail?name=tds2pdb102.zip

Answer (score 4):

Besides tds2pdb (see my comment on map2dbg) you can also use my minidump viewer on Delphi programs:

<strike>https://github.com/andremussche/asmprofiler/blob/master/Source/MiniDumpReader/ViewMinidump.exe.</strike>

https://github.com/andremussche/asmprofiler/blob/master/Releases/ViewMinidump.exe

Then you don't need to convert to .dbg or to .pdb, but it directly reads various Delphi debug files (.map, .tds/.td32, and j.dbg).

Comment: Your link to ViewMinidump.exe produces a 404.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of [cv2pdb](https://github.com/rainers/cv2pdb) tool can convert the DBGs made with map2dbg into PDB files.

So, if you've previously made your DBGs like this:
map2dbg App.exe

Just add this command afterwards:
cv2pdb -s. App.exe

-s. parameter is necessary to separate the method names from the class names with a point.

cv2pdb built for Win32 on the current sources can to downloaded from [here](https://yadi.sk/d/lAobtdXl3TxDh3).