# Can I emit debug symbols from my Delphi application that Process Explorer can use?

Tags: delphi, debugging, winapi

I'm investigating a performance issue with my application written in Delphi 2010. Does Delphi emit symbols that [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) can use when viewing the currently running threads so I can see the function names?

I've blocked out the name of my executable, but you can see it only gives me the memory address of the function, and I'd like to have the resolved function name if possible (like I have for ole32.dll and ntdll.dll because I am using the MS symbol server).

I know this can be done for [VC++ applications and WinDbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734272/how-to-use-windbg-to-analyze-the-crash-dump-for-vc-application/758840#758840)...can it be done with Delphi applications and Process Explorer?

[image]

Comment: See [this answer on how to use map2dbg](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1240500/9842)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yep, what you need to do is make sure the project is compiled with debug info and that the linker emits a *detailed* map file (project link options). Not sure, but you may also have to check the "include remote debug symbols" on the linker options.

When you have that, you can use a utility to convert the map to the dbg format that ProcessExplorer uses.

We do this at work whenever we need to get a stack trace on a hung thread on one of our testservers.

The Map2Dbg utility we use: https://github.com/andremussche/map2dbg

Comment: +1 I did not know about this and will find it very useful, not that my software ever hangs of course!!  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: of course not, neither does ours :-) It doesn't hang, it merely pauses for reflection!

Comment: Delphi supports reflection now, as well as RTTI?

Comment: @Martin no, Run Time Type Information (RTTI) in Delphi simply provides the data for what is called reflection (or introspection) in other languages